# Select only text visible on webpage, from DOM parent element

Tags: javascript, jquery, firefox, jquery-selectors, firefox-addon

Inside a content script of my work-in-progress Firefox add-on, I have a variable named `element` containing the reference toward a generic DOM element. This element may contain children or grandchildren, which in turn may contain text nodes visible on the rendered webpage.

My goal is to extract all the visible text contained in this DOM `element`. Internet Explorer has the [innerText](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ie/ms533899%28v=vs.85%29.aspx) method, which does exactly what I need but, unfortunately, that is not a standard method and does not work/exist outside of IE.

Firefox comes with a similar [textContent](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.textContent) property which closely imitates `innerText`, but fails to filter off invisible text contained within tags such as `<script>` and `<style>`.

Looking for a jQuery solution, I believe I'm close to find one; I've come to:

```
text = $(element).filter(":visible").text();
```

This statement correctly extracts the text contained in all the children of `element`, but invisible text from `<script>` tags is not filtered off. Googling around, I couldn't find any reference solution to the problem.

Comment: do you wanna exclude the texts from `<script>` tags or something else that I'm not understanding?

Comment: Theres a property on the node.textContent try node.nodeType you should be able to tell from there

Answer (score 0):

When you do `node.textContent` do a test on `node.nodeType`.

If nodeType == some number then its visibl.

The numbers are here:

https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Node.nodeType?redirectlocale=en-US&redirectslug=DOM%2FNode.nodeType

### Name |  Value

- ELEMENT_NODE |    1
- ATTRIBUTE_NODE |  2
- TEXT_NODE |   3
- CDATA_SECTION_NODE |  4
- ENTITY_REFERENCE_NODE |   5
- ENTITY_NODE | 6
- PROCESSING_INSTRUCTION_NODE | 7
- COMMENT_NODE |    8
- DOCUMENT_NODE |   9
- DOCUMENT_TYPE_NODE |  10
- DOCUMENT_FRAGMENT_NODE |  11
- NOTATION_NODE |   12

Let us know which nodeType is for visible text we'll all learn something

Comment: I think this suggestion does not address the visibility of those elements hidden by CSS, such as with the attributes "show:none" or "left: -100em". The jQuery filter(":visible") method should instead take care of that, and be ready to use. Or maybe that filter doesn't work as I expect? Perhaps I mistyped something? Actually I am totally new to jQuery.

Comment: Did you test out the nodeType while things are visible and not? Just curious. If it really doesnt work then ill invesitgate more. Actually i think thats how `:visible` works it checks nodeType and then checks style `display!=none` and `visibility!='hidden'` and `opacity>0`

Comment: Actually they have their set of rules for `:visible` its clarified here: http://api.jquery.com/visible-selector/

Answer (score 0):

This appears to work.  I've only done a quick test so far.  You might need to fiddle with it if you have other issues besides `<script>` and `<style>` tags (e.g., CSS rules that affect visibility, etc.):

```
function getText(node){
    if(!node )return;
    var cloned=node.cloneNode(true);
    var removeList=Array.from(cloned.querySelectorAll("script,style")||[]);
    removeList.forEach(node=>node.parentNode.removeChild(node));
    return cloned.textContent;
}
```